# "no matching function for call to" HAS ME BAFFLED

Tags: c++

I'm back again with this PCNN code from a text book.
I'm getting the "no matching function call for"  error in pcn2d.cc in lines associated
with variables F, L, U, T, and Y. Here are the class files, the code file, and the compiler log:

rimage.h

```
    //
    // rimage.h  
    //  
    //  
    // Jason M. Kinser  
    // 15 October 1995  
    // rimage.h  
    // an image of real elements  
    // 1 April 1996 - added histogram  
    // 15 April 1996 - addeed hgradientbox  
    // 27 June 1996 - a dded /= rimage  
    // 7 July 1996 - added / rimage, Smooth  
    //  
        #include "matrix.h"  
        #ifndef RIMAGE    
        #define RIMAGE  
        typedef unsigned short word;    
        typedef unsigned long dword;  

        class rimage : public matrix {  
    public:  
        rimage( void );  
        rimage( int, int );  
        rimage( rimage & );  
        rimage & operator=( const matrix & A );  
        rimage & operator=( const rimage & A );  
        rimage & operator/=( int );  
    // Math  
        rimage operator+( float );  
        rimage operator+( const rimage & );  
        rimage operator*( const rimage & ); // element  
        rimage operator*( float );  
        friend rimage operator+( float, const rimage & );  
        friend rimage operator*( float, const rimage & );  
        rimage Convolve( rimage & );  
    // Image conversions  
        void UpsideDown( void );  
    // Input / Output  
        void SaveTarga( char * );  
    } ;  
    #endif
```

pcnn2d.h

```
    //  
    // pcnn2d.h  
    // A 2D Pulse-Coupled Neural Network  
    // Jason Kinser  
    // 15 April 1996  
    //  
    #include "rimage.h "  
    class PCNN {  
    int vert, horz;  
    rimage Quantized ( void );  
    public:  
         rimage F, L, U, T, Y, K;  
         float af, al, at, beta, vf, vl, vt;  
         PCNN( int, int);       // The two dimensions  
         PCNN( const PCNN & );  // copy  
         ~PCNN( void );  
    int KernVert( void) const;   
    int KernHorz( void) const;  
    void StdK( void );  
    int Iterate ( rimage & );  
    int FastIterate( rimage & ); // uses fast linking   
    void Clear( void );  
    void Save( char * );  
    void Load( char * );  
    };
```

pcnn2d.cc

```
    //  
    // pcnn2d.cc  
    // The Pulse-Coupled Neural Network  
    //  
    // Jason Kinser  
    // 15 April 1996  

    #include <math.h>  
    #include <stdlib.h>  
    #include "pcnn2d.h"  

    PCNN::PCNN( int V, int H )  
    {  
        vert = V;   horz = H;  
        F.New( V, H );  
        L.New( V, H );  
        U.New( V, H );  
        T.New( V, H );  
        Y.New( V, H );  
        K.New( 5, 5 );  
        af = 10.0; al = 1.0; at = 5.0;  
        beta = 0.1;  
        vf = 0.5;   vl = 0.5;   vt = 20.0;  
        StdK();  
    }  

    PCNN::PCNN( const PCNN & P )
    {
        vert = P.vert; horz = P.horz;
        F.New( vert, horz );
        L.New( vert, horz );
        U.New( vert, horz );
        T.New( vert, horz );
        Y.New( vert, horz );
        K.New( P.KernVert ( ), P.KernHorz( ) );
        F = P.F;    L = P.L;        U = P.U;
        T = P.T;    Y = P.Y;        K = P.K;
        af = P.af; al = P.al;   at = P.at;
        beta = P.beta;
        vf = P.vf; vl = P.vl; vt = P.vt;
    }
    PCNN::~PCNN( void )
    {
        F.Dispose();    L.Dispose();    U.Dispose();
        T.Dispose();    Y.Dispose();    K.Dispose();
    }

    int PCNN::KernVert( void ) const
    // returns the vertical dimension of the kernel
    {   return K.Vert( ); }

    int PCNN::KernHorz( void ) const
    {   return K.Horz( ); }

    void PCNN::StdK( void )
    {   int i, j, kv, kh; float val;
        kv = K.Vert(); kh = K.Horz();
        for ( i=0; i<kv; i++ ) for ( j=0; j<kh; j++ ) 
        {
            val = hypot( i-kv/2, j-kh/2 );
            if( val != 0.0 ) val = 1.0/val;
            else val = 1.0;
            K[i][j] = val;
        }
    }
    rimage PCNN::Quantized ( void )
    {
        int i,j; rimage ans( vert, horz );
        rimage work( vert, horz ), k( 3,3 );
        k.Clear( 1.0 ); 
        work = Y.Convolve( k );     //ERROR LINE 74
    for ( i=0; i<work.Vert(); i++ ) for ( j=0; j<work.Horz(); j++ )
        if( work[i][j] > 1.0 ) ans[i][j] = 1.0;
        else ans [i][j] = 0.0;
    return ans;
    }
    int PCNN::Iterate( rimage & A )
    {
        rimage work( F.Vert() , F.Horz() );
        work = Y.Convolve( K );              //ERROR LINE 83
        F = exp( -1.0/af ) * F + vf * work + A; //ERROR LINE 84
        L = exp( -1.0/al ) * L + vl* work;  //ERROR LINE 85
        U = F * (1.0 + beta * L);           //ERROR LINE 86
        for( int i=0; i<vert; i++ ) for ( int j = 0; j<horz; j++ )
            if( U[i][j] > T[i][j] )
            Y[i][j] = 1.0;
            else
            Y[i][j] = 0.0;
        T = exp ( -1.0/at ) * T + vt * Y;   //ERROR LINE 92
        return int( Y.Sum( ) );
    }
    int PCNN::FastIterate( rimage & A )
    {
        rimage work ( F.Vert(), F.Horz()), Q ( F. Vert () , F.Horz ());
        int n=0;
        if( vf != 0 ) work = Y.Convolve( K );   //ERROR LINE 99
        F = exp( - 1.0/af ) * F + vf * work + A;    //ERROR LINE 100
        Y.Clear();
        do {
            Q = Y; n++;
            L = Quantized( );       //ERROR LINE 104
            U = F * (1.0 + beta * L);   //ERROR LINE 105
            for( int i=0; i<vert; i++ ) for( int j=0; j<horz; j++ )                 
            if( U[i][j] > T[i][j] )
            Y[i][j] = 1.0;
        } 
        while( (Q + Y).Sum() > 1 && n < 5);
        T = exp( -1.0/at ) * T + vt * Y;    //ERROR LINE 111
        return int ( Y.Sum( ) );
    }
```

The compiler log:

```
g++.exe -c "PCNN Code/pcnn2d.c" -o   
"PCNN Code/pcnn2d.o" -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/include"    
-I"C:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2/backward"    
-I"C:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2/mingw32"    
-I"C:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2"  
-I"C:/Dev-Cpp/include"     


In file included from C:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2/backward/iostream.h:31,  
                 from PCNN Code/vector.h:9,  
                 from PCNN Code/matrix.h:10,  
                 from PCNN Code/rimage.h :15,  
                 from PCNN Code/pcnn2d.h:8,  
                 from PCNN Code/pcnn2d.c:12:  
C:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2/backward/backward_warning.h:32:2:   
warning: #warning This file includes at least one deprecated or antiquated header.   
Please consider using one of the 32 headers found in section 17.4.1.2 of the C++ standard.   Examples include substituting the <X> header for the <X.h> header for C++ includes, or <iostream> instead of the deprecated header <iostream.h>. To disable this warning use -Wno-deprecated.  
PCNN Code/pcnn2d.c: In member function `rimage PCNN::Quantized()':  
PCNN Code/pcnn2d.c:74: error: no matching function for call to `rimage::rimage(rimage)'  
PCNN Code/rimage.h :27: note: candidates are: rimage::rimage(rimage&)  

PCNN Code/pcnn2d.c: In member function `int PCNN::Iterate(rimage&)':  
PCNN Code/pcnn2d.c:83: error: no matching function for call to `rimage::rimage(rimage)'  

PCNN Code/rimage.h :27: note: candidates are: rimage::rimage(rimage&)  
PCNN Code/pcnn2d.c:84: error: no matching function for call to `rimage::rimage(rimage)'  

PCNN Code/rimage.h :27: note: candidates are: rimage::rimage(rimage&)  
PCNN Code/pcnn2d.c:84: error: no matching function for call to `rimage::rimage(rimage)'  

PCNN Code/rimage.h :27: note: candidates are: rimage::rimage(rimage&)  
PCNN Code/pcnn2d.c:85: error: no matching function for call to `rimage::rimage(rimage)'  

PCNN Code/rimage.h :27: note: candidates are: rimage::rimage(rimage&)  
PCNN Code/pcnn2d.c:85: error: no matching function for call to `rimage::rimage(rimage)'  

PCNN Code/rimage.h :27: note: candidates are: rimage::rimage(rimage&)  
PCNN Code/pcnn2d.c:86: error: no matching function for call to `rimage::rimage(rimage)'  

PCNN Code/rimage.h :27: note: candidates are: rimage::rimage(rimage&)  
PCNN Code/pcnn2d.c:86: error: no matching function for call to `rimage::rimage(rimage)'  

PCNN Code/rimage.h :27: note: candidates are: rimage::rimage(rimage&)  
PCNN Code/pcnn2d.c:86: error: no matching function for call to `rimage::rimage(rimage)'  

PCNN Code/rimage.h :27: note: candidates are: rimage::rimage(rimage&)  
PCNN Code/pcnn2d.c:92: error: no matching function for call to `rimage::rimage(rimage)'  

PCNN Code/rimage.h :27: note: candidates are: rimage::rimage(rimage&)  
PCNN Code/pcnn2d.c:92: error: no matching function for call to `rimage::rimage(rimage)'  

PCNN Code/rimage.h :27: note: candidates are: rimage::rimage(rimage&)  
PCNN Code/pcnn2d.c: In member function `int PCNN::FastIterate(rimage&)':  
PCNN Code/pcnn2d.c:99: error: no matching function for call to `rimage::rimage(rimage)'  
PCNN Code/rimage.h :27: note: candidates are: rimage::rimage(rimage&)  
PCNN Code/pcnn2d.c:100: error: no matching function for call to `rimage::rimage(rimage)'  
PCNN Code/rimage.h :27: note: candidates are: rimage::rimage(rimage&)  
PCNN Code/pcnn2d.c:100: error: no matching function for call to `rimage::rimage(rimage)'  
PCNN Code/rimage.h :27: note: candidates are: rimage::rimage(rimage&)  
PCNN Code/pcnn2d.c:104: error: no matching function for call to `rimage::rimage(rimage)'  
PCNN Code/rimage.h :27: note: candidates are: rimage::rimage(rimage&)  
PCNN Code/pcnn2d.c:105: error: no matching function for call to `rimage::rimage(rimage)'  
PCNN Code/rimage.h :27: note: candidates are: rimage::rimage(rimage&)  
PCNN Code/pcnn2d.c:105: error: no matching function for call to `rimage::rimage(rimage)'  
PCNN Code/rimage.h :27: note: candidates are: rimage::rimage(rimage&)  
PCNN Code/pcnn2d.c:105: error: no matching function for call to `rimage::rimage(rimage)'  

PCNN Code/rimage.h :27: note: candidates are: rimage::rimage(rimage&)  
PCNN Code/pcnn2d.c:111: error: no matching function for call to `rimage::rimage(rimage)'  
PCNN Code/rimage.h :27: note: candidates are: rimage::rimage(rimage&)  
PCNN Code/pcnn2d.c:111: error: no matching function for call to `rimage::rimage(rimage)'  
PCNN Code/rimage.h :27: note: candidates are: rimage::rimage(rimage&)  

make.exe: *** ["PCNN Code/pcnn2d.o"] Error 1  
Execution terminated
```

Comment: Since this is C++ file, shouldn't the file extension be `.cc` or `.cpp`?

Comment: Can you please remove the implementations of all the member functions and retain only one which has the error? So that it will be easy to understand and solve.

Comment: Both points taken. This is code from a text book that I'm intentionally compiling verbatim. I added more than necessary to ensure that nothing critical was left out. I got my problem solved with the forum's help and I'm happy.

Answer (score 2):

It talks about not exactly matching a call to `rimage::rimage(rimage&)`. This usually means that you are trying to copy from a temporary object, which could use this copy constructor **if** it had been `rimage::rimage(const rimage&)`.

Why is it not? Because the code is 15 years old, from before there was a C++ standard?

Comment: Thanks again guys. This fixed the problem and I got the project to compile successfully

Answer (score 0):

yup - your copy constructor must be `rimage(const rimage& other)` -- note the additional `const`.

ms's compiler supported this as an *extension*, for some reason.

with the `const` in place, a conforming compiler will be allowed (by the standard) to create/use a temporary `rimage` instance, unless there is a conversion and you have declared the constructor `explicit`.

solution: you will either have to

1) provide a copy constructor which uses a const qualifier for its argument

2) or explicitly create a non-const `rimage` instance and pass that for copy.

which is better/applicable depends on the actual implementation, and in some cases, the costs/side-effects of enabling copying.

Comment: You're correct that the copy constructor needs a const, but that's not a compiler extension.  The spec explicitly allows you to write a copy constructor that takes its argument by non-const reference.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the problem. I like this forum! You guys are right on top of things with good answers.